# E-mail tracking script

Tags: php, javascript, email

I need to send some emails and track down if links within that e-mails were clicked. I know some services as mailchimp.com, campaignmonitor.com.., but they are too robust, include their logo etc.

I want something lightweight, some php (js) script which I upload to my server and then use unique link within every email I send, to write some log which link in which email was clicked. Any tutorial or link to script will be great.

Comment: MailChimp and CampaignMonitor don't include their logos in your e-mails, certainly not in their paid plans.

Comment: Are you always linking to the same (your own) site or are you linking to a variety of sites? And you can forget about JS - Outlook bins any JS in any emails, and if Outlook wont do it, it's effectively useless cos you've just lost at least 50% of your target market...

Comment: ceejayoz, I strongly prefer free solution and in that case they include their logos.

Comment: DaveRandom, I will link to one site. I thinked that it'll not work with js, byt I wasn't sure. As I was looking for an answer, I discover, that many guys wrote their own script, but none of them make it available and unfortunately I'm no php programmer:(

Comment: I think what you are after is a link forwarder, e.g. you set the URL in the emails to `http://mydomain.tld/linktracker.php?linkid=mylinkid&customerid=mr_a.n.other` and then have linktracker.php do a 302 redirect to the actual address - am I on the right lines?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the links are all to your site, then simply add a query parameter to identify which email the link is in (user id, email id), so you end up with:

```
<a href="yoursite.com/somepage.html?emailID=spam campaign #2&userID=recipient@example.com">...</a>
```

which you can then parse out of your server's access log.

If the links point at multiple different sites, which you may not control, then you'll need a simple redirector script. A link which points at YOUR site to capture the user's click, and then simply redirect to whatever site they're supposed to end up on:

```
<a href="yoursite.com/click.php?link=othersite.com/someotherpage&userID=recipient@example.com">...</a>
```

Comment: Marc B, thank you, all of the links will be to my site. I need some tutorial or ready to use script. I have no idea how to handle that unique id, assign it correct e-mail address and write down a log.

Comment: No need to write a log. It'll be done automatically by the webserver. You'd just need to scan the regular access log to locate the particularly hits from these links.

Comment: No, you don't. You need a PHP book and some patience.

Comment: Marc B, thank you, I will forward it to my friend, which is more familiar with php to make it done and reply back.

Comment: Tomalak, that would be great. I'm not lazy to do that, but this is the first time I need something like this and propably the last time for a long time and therefore I have not enough time to study new languages for one-time project.

Comment: @Mark B - isn't that pretty inefficient for more that just a few hits? Surely the way to attack this is with a redirect page and a database engine that gives you the ability to search without having to parse an entire file every time, even if links are all on your own site?

Comment: @Dave: I doubt OP is running an FB/Google-sized operation, so grepping an access log for a particular fingerprint shouldn't take more than a couple minutes (assuming some semi-regular log rotation) at most.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (very) basic framework for a PHP/MySQL redirect page that logs who arrived there and redirects people to the right place. This assumes your email links are in the format `http://mydomain.tld/linktracker.php?linkid=mylinkid&customerid=mr_a.n.other`.

```
<?php

  // Do your DB connection stuff here

  // Fetch information about where to redirect people to
  $dbresult = mysql_query("SELECT `url` FROM `email_links` WHERE `linkid` = '{$_GET['linkid']}'");
  $linkdata = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult);

  // Log the fact that this links was clicked
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `email_clicks` (`linkid`,`customerid`) VALUES ('{$_GET['linkid']}','{$_GET['customerid']}')");

  // Redirect to the real page
  header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
  header('Location: '.$linkdata['url']);

?>
```

There is no error handling in the above script and obviously I don't know how your database is/would be structured, so you will have to modify it a lot...

Comment: Thank you for your effort DaveRandom, your code looks great, but as I mentioned, I'm not a php programmer, so I need step-by-step tutorial or complete script. I don't know how to make it work with db:(

Comment: @culter what do you have at the moment? How are you creating your links, and how you *want* to keep track of them?

Comment: DaveRandom, I wanted to send that emails without tracking, but today I realized that it will be a good idea to know which is the response, so I have almost nothing. I plan to change that unique id manualy, because it will be only tens of e-mails..

Comment: I'm afraid your probably either going to have to learn some PHP to do this or employ someone who already knows some... It's not a huge job and shouldn't take an experienced developer more than a couple of hours to throw something simple together for you.

Comment: I just found http://www.php-development.ru/php-scripts/click-tracker.php Maybe it will do what I need. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try pommo mailer(http://pommo.org/Main_Page ).Its opensource,and you can have total contol but you have to configure it on you server(you can find some cheaper hosting),you should have hosting for this  and you should have some php knowledge . 
for Tracking mail:

If u want to see that how many person have opened your mail.
you can use pixel  (http://pixelsite.info/) 
I am doing by this way..

and To track that how many user have clicked your links you can use google URL Shortner